# HttpClient timeout on Braintree call in Blazor

Tags: websocket, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

I'm deploying my .Net 6, Blazor Server site for the first time on shared hosting.  It's all seems to work so far bar two things.

In the browser console (Chrome) I get an error:

```
Error 1
blazor.server.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.mysite.co.uk/_blazor?id=qW5eCRVc_HbgSWt8iESawA' failed: 
Information: (WebSockets transport) There was an error with the transport.
Error: Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets': Error: WebSocket failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled.
Warning: Failed to connect via WebSockets, using the Long Polling fallback transport. This may be due to a VPN or proxy blocking the connection. To troubleshoot this, visit https://aka.ms/blazor-server-using-fallback-long-polling.
```

The page seems to work & I've added all the CSP entries I can find so that's the only error left.

Error 2 is when I call Braintree to capture a payment. That's the only Braintree call & it works fine locally.

```
Transaction.SubmitForSettlementAsync(transactionId, amount)
gets an exception : The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 60 seconds elapsing.
```

I have no idea why that is & assume is blocking is call.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think that you have a problem with your server configuration, you need to check if the server supports `WebSocket`. Try `Firebase` it is free and supports blazor!

Answer (score 0):

For this warning:

> Warning: Failed to connect via WebSockets, using the Long Polling fallback transport. This may be due to a VPN or proxy blocking the connection. To troubleshoot this, visit https://aka.ms/blazor-server-using-fallback-long-polling.

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/publish-to-azure-web-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-the-app-in-azure-app-service

> For apps hosted without the Azure SignalR Service, enable:
>
> - ARR Affinity to route requests from a user back to the same App Service > instance. The default setting is On.
> - Web Sockets to allow the Web Sockets transport to function. The default setting is Off.
>
> 1. In the Azure portal, navigate to the web app in App Services.
> 2. Open Configuration > General settings.
> 3. Set **Web sockets** to **On**.
> 4. Verify that **ARR affinity** is set to **On**.